# Django celery: Cannot connect to amqp:// [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, windows, rabbitmq, celery

I am preparing for production. I was testing on OS X and now in the transitioning it to Windows 2008. It worked fine for OS X.

I have created a new user. Added a vhost and set permission for my user using the vhost. RabbitMQ service is running.

permission set: `rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p vhost user ".*" ".*" ".*"`

I still continue to get the error. Not sure what else I am missing.

`settings.py`:

```
# user, password and vhost are filled properly and do exist in RabbitMQ
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:password@localhost:5672/vhost//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
```

`celery.py`:

```
app = Celery('myapp', backend='amqp', broker=amqp://user:password@localhost:5672/vhost//)
```

`python manage.py celery worker --app=myapp.celery --no-color --loglevel=info`

output:

```
 -------------- celery@inst v3.1.23 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         myapp:0x32b5610
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://user:**@localhost:5672/vhost//
- ** ---------- .> results:
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . bpts.tasks.add
  . bpts.tasks.f
  . bpts.tasks.mul
  . bpts.tasks.send_email_message
  . bpts.tasks.xsum
  . myapp.celery.debug_task

[2017-09-08 07:36:56,638: INFO/Worker-1] child process 4776 calling self.run()
[2017-09-08 07:36:56,966: INFO/Worker-1] child process 5328 calling self.run()
[2017-09-08 07:36:57,325: INFO/Worker-1] child process 4116 calling self.run()
[2017-09-08 07:36:57,388: INFO/Worker-1] child process 3720 calling self.run()
[2017-09-08 07:37:00,013: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://
user:**@127.0.0.1:5672/vhost//: [Errno 10054] An existing conne
ction was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

Comment: was hoping if anyone had any insight or if any more info is needed to help resolve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I am not sure the direct solution to getting it working.

Here are a couple things I did that resulted in it working on my production server.

Originally my broker url was `amqp://user:password@localhost:5672/vhost//` I removed the end `//`, removed port # resulting in `amqp://user:password@localhost/vhost`

This is supposed to help with the admin site for RabbitMQ
`rabbitmqctl set_user_tags user administrator`

Set permission for root vhost, I set my own but didn't seem to work so I tried this.
`rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / user ".*" ".*" ".*"`.

Also, note for people using production. Remember to delete the guest user.

`rabbitmqctl delete_user <user>`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be something about celery worker spawning more than 1 process (--concurrency /  --autoscale), leading to multiple connections at the same time to the db.

I can't confirm this, since I'm also struggling with something like that.

Comment: Hello, please don't post answers if you're not sure it's the right solution. Answers should avoid speculation as much as possible. Anything else should be a comment or a question.